# I can't leave a comment or star levels, why?

Tags: super-mario-maker

Could it be because the one I'm trying to star or comment uses my same system?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you can’t comment is because that feature went when miiverse went.

All comments were stored on miiverse, so when they discounted miiverse, they deleted all the comments.

R.I.P. miiverse.

Answer (score 2):

It could be because you are using another profile to make a game then using another profile on the console to star the level that you make. You cant do that because nintendo banned it